# Connecting to postgres from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, homebrew

I've installed postgres via homebrew.

brew info postgres                                                                                              ⏎
postgresql: stable 9.6.2 (bottled), HEAD
Object-relational database system

When I try and rake db:create

I get the error:

"could not connect to server: Connection refused"

If I run 
ps aux | grep postgres
=>

But running 
brew services start postgresql                                                                                  ⏎
Service `postgresql` already started, use `brew services restart postgresql` to restart.

I'm on OSX 10.11.6

Why can't rails connect to postgrsql?

Comment: Did you set up the values inside your database.yml file?

Comment: yep.  running "psql" gives an error connection too.